# Beep sounds when pressing keys in a form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I have three controls on my form - a texbox, button and a picturebox. After clicking a button, both textbox and button itself become inactive. Also I have and `Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)` to send pressed buttons that will be displayed on picturebox, but for some reason everytime I press any key it beeps. I've noticed that it happens only with button and `TextBox` deactivated. Why is that happening and how do I press keys without that annoying beeps?

`e.SuppressKeyPress = true` is preventing the input of keys to control, I don't need that, I just need to rid of that sound (why is it there anyway, when I'm disabling two controls?)

UPD: I think the problem is that `PictureBox` doesn't have a focus and also a `KeyDown` event.

Answer (score 0):

> `e.SuppressKeyPress = true` is preventing the input of keys to control, I don't need that, I just need to rid of that sound

You should set the `SuppressKeyPress` only if you handled the event manually. So typically for <kbd>Enter</kbd>/<kbd>Escape</kbd> buttons:

```
// suppress key only if you handled the keystroke
void txtValue_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        if (IsModified)
            SaveData();
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        if (IsModified)
            ResetData();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Application beeps if I press any key on keyboard, not just Enter or Alt or something. Everty key that I press make this sound. But this happens only when other controls disabled. I can't see how can I use this code to my case.

Comment: Does it mean that you change the focus on each keystroke? In this case maybe you should always suppress the handling.

Comment: No, I don't change focus at all. I suggest it's done automatically when other controls are disables. But beep sounds on every keystroke, no matter what I pressed.